# How to bind an input button to an li that needs to execute PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to delete files manually on my site. I created a list of all the files that can be deleted and each file has an input button. I already made a sort of connection with jQuery.

The problem lies in the fact that the button doesn't recognize it's parents hence it doesn't send any information.

This is my PHP of the delete function:

```
if(isset($_POST["destroyFile"])) {

        $filename = $_POST["remove_file"];
        $file = 'views/home/added_files/'.$filename.'.php';
        $this->query("DELETE FROM page_context WHERE file_name='$filename'");
        $rows = $this->resultSet();
        unlink($file);
    }
```

I call each row with an for loop and this is the echo of it.

```
echo "<li name=''>$filename[$i]<input type='submit' name='destroyFile' value='Remove File'></li>";
```

and it's not much but this is my jquery which changes the name of the parent which is li. Doesn't seem it's connected to it. It just changes the name and nothing more.

```
$("li").on("click", "input", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().attr("name", "remove_file");
    alert("hey");
});
```

The jQuery above makes the name for the li and that name should be called after destroyFile isset.

Is this even feasible? Because php is server sided and jQuery is more website sided coding.

**Note:** I made an input field where I could type in the file name. This worked. So the PHP code is fine and dandy.

**Note 2:** This is a bad habit of mine but I re-use $variables. $filename in my php code isn't the same as the $filename in the echo. Just a warning in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the submit button with:

```
<input type='submit' name='destroyFile' value='Remove File'>
```

This means, that you can access the value of the specific button in PHP with `$_POST['destroyFile']`, since you named the `input` `'destroyFile'`. Its value is always `'Remove File'`.

To provide an specific file you can set the value of the button to `$filename[$i]` instead.

```
echo "<li>remove file <button type='submit' name='destroyFile' value='{$filename[$i]}'>{$filename[$i]}</button></li>";
```

Calling `$filename = $_POST['destroyFile'];` will now save the specific filename into the variable.

Comment: Thanks all lot. With some tweaking I was able to perform what I wanted. Without your help, it would have taken me way longer.